# Opening a file; but skipping each line

Tags: c++, fstream

I wanted to know how you skip lines as you open the file with `fstream`. when I open the file it returns all the numbers bunched up together like "201051535402530"

here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string testing;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("inputfile");
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile, testing);
        cout << testing;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the inputfile is listed as:

```
20
10
5
15
35
40
25
30
```

Comment: Change `cout << testing;` to `cout << testing << " ";`

Comment: Or `cout << testing << "\n";` to print each item on its own line.

Comment: Also, who teaches  `while (!eof)` ? It's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `getline()` reads a line, it discards the trailing newline.  If you want one printed in your output, you need to put it there yourself:

```
cout << testing << endl;
```